# How to convert interface{} to bytes.Buffer

Tags: go, type-conversion

How to convert `interface{}` to `bytes.Buffer`?

Minimal [example](http://play.golang.org/p/4WDoVq1EaM)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func ToJson5(any interface{}) string {
    if any == nil {
        return `''`
    }
    switch any.(type) {
    case bytes.Buffer: // return as is
        return any.(bytes.Buffer).String()
    // other types works fine
    }
    return ``
}

func main() {
    x := bytes.Buffer{}
    fmt.Println(ToJson5(x))
}
```

The errors was:

```
main.go:14: cannot call pointer method on any.(bytes.Buffer)
main.go:14: cannot take the address of any.(bytes.Buffer)
```

When changed to `bytes.Buffer{}` (that I think less correct), the error was:

```
main.go:13: bytes.Buffer literal (type bytes.Buffer) is not a type
main.go:14: bytes.Buffer literal is not a type
```

Comment: Usually that type is used as a pointer so normally `x := new(bytes.Buffer)` but you could also use it with `&x` (e.g. `var x bytes.Buffer; fmt.Fprintln(&x, "Foo")`). You likely don't want to pass one by value like you have though! Then you'd also use `case *bytes.Buffer` and `any.(*bytes.Buffer).String()` which should work as you'd then be calling a pointer method on a pointer. However using `v := any.(type)` as in icza's answer is easier.

Comment: @DaveC Note that though in this case `any.(*bytes.Buffer).String()` will not work because the value passed is _not_ a pointer therefore you can't obtain a pointer from it using type assertion. It would only work if the function would be called like this: `ToJson5(&x))`.

Comment: @icza, that's why I also mentioned using `&x` and that passing a `bytes.Buffer` by value is a bad idea. Notice my use of the word "then".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) in the [Type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) to have the typed value in the `case` branches:

```
switch v := any.(type) {
case bytes.Buffer: // return as is
    return v.String() // Here v is of type bytes.Buffer
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1Ghqr70Gw5).

Quoting form the spec:

> The TypeSwitchGuard may include a short variable declaration. When that form is used, the variable is declared at the beginning of the implicit block in each clause. In clauses with a case listing exactly one type, the variable has that type; otherwise, the variable has the type of the expression in the TypeSwitchGuard.

Comment: ah I see, I never know about this XD